# How to copy dvds using HandBrake under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I can get handbrake to encode a dvd just fine but after that what do i use to write it to the blank dvdrw? Am using ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Hello Mark Vaughn, Welcome to Askubuntu. Have you tried to burn your encoded folder/files in Brasero? I can't say for sure that Handbrake will burn the DVD into a disc but it is used for ripping from originals. Please give Brasero a try and inform us if you succeeded. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are encoding from MPEG2 to MPEG4 and from MPEG4 back to MPEG2 format. You are not only loosing quality with unnecessary encoding steps, you are also loosing the original structure of the DVD including menus and depending on your Handbrake settings chapters, subtitles and additional (multichannel) audio tracks.

Handbrake was not made for copying DVDs.

For simple cloning use `dvdbackup` with `--mirror` parameter. Then either use your favorite burning software and [pray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdrkit#History) or generate a compliant ISO image yourself and burn it.

If resizing is necessary use [DeVeDe](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/devede/).

Note that you might experience issues with the copy protection of some DVDs. While DeCSS works fine, most tools for reading and manipulating the DVD structure expect a working structure and cannot handle errors (that have been deliberately put in there).